# Jruby newbie: Installing gems

Tags: java, ruby, rvm, jruby

I have jruby-1.7.0 installed via rvm on OSX Mountain Lion. I know Ruby reasonably well, but have very little experience with Java.

After getting it set up, the first thing I've tried to do is install a gem (specifically `gem install bundler`). Nothing happens, and I am not returned to prompt. Only sign of action is that my macbook's fan cranks up and, after a few minutes, the machine gets pretty warm.

I can't really figure out how to track down what's happening, and more importantly, how to fix it. Any suggestions on how to diagnose this?

Answer (score 1):

I think `gem install --verbose bundler` should give you more feedback on what's going on, which is good if you're wondering if anything's happening at all.

`gem env` shows how rubygems is set up. Running it will also show that at least some part of rubygems is working as it ought to.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed it and to install a gem, you need to use the specific installation of gem for jruby.

Answer (score 0):

you might be using older java, jruby will work a lot faster using latest release of Java 1.7 or the experimental java 1.8